# Why am I getting a HTTP 400 error?

Tags: node.js, http, express, passport.js

I found that the 400 HTTP error is something with syntax but I cannot find anything wrong with my syntax, could someone help take a look at it?

```
<!- My form view-->
<h3>Login</h3>
<form action="/home/login" method="post">
  Enter your usernmae: <input type="text" name="user" value=""><br>
  Enter your password: <input type="password" name="pwd" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter">
</form>




//controller added to my app.js
app.use('/home', indexController);




//in router.js
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  req.session.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/home/' + req.user.user);
  });
});
```

Comment: What URL are you getting the 400 on?

Comment: just my localhost:3000/home/login

Comment: Could it be that the login is failing?

Comment: i double checked the user and pass and its all correct

Comment: `console.log(err)` inside the `if (err)` block to see the details

Comment: i figured it out, it had to do with my passport usage. where I declared my username and password in my Schema.